# How to call inter related async method within a web api method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api method that needs to call 2 asynchronous method from another party, and the result of the first async method is required in order to call the second async method. I have something like the below code, which obviously doesn't work as with the await keyword, my understanding is it will go to the next line and continue and at the same time return a Task object to the caller.

A brief explanation of what I need from this method is that, I need to get a token from a third party async method, after that, base on the token, I need to do some stuff, then use the token to call another aysnc method from the third party again.

```
            public async Task<ResponseObj> DoSomething()
            {
                var token = await GetTokenAsync();

                DoStuff1();

                var stuff = await CreateStuff(token);

                SaveStuff(stuff);

                ResponseObj response = new ResponseObj(stuff);

                return response;

            }
```

I've read a few article and example online and some people say instead of await, I can use Task.Result so that the next depending call won't run until the task return the result, some people use Task.Wait and seems like it will wait until the task finishes. I've tried both and failed to achieve my expected result, which CreateStuffAsync can't start until I have the result from GetTokenAsync.

Can someone point out what I've done wrong?  Let's say if the first await already return a task to the caller, then what happen when the second await is reached? Am I supposed to not have more than 1 await in the method especially when one rely on the other one?

Comment: Please add the "below code".

Comment: done, sorry I was formatting the code so that it can be shown right.

Comment: Did you actually test the code to find out that this will in fact do what you want?

Comment: *"which obviously doesn't work as with the await keyword"* looks like it would work to me, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Please elaborate on what actually goes wrong when you try to do the above code? Likely your problem is not here, but in the code that calls the function you provided.

Comment: DoStuff will get triggered, but when CreateStuff is being called, the token is null as it is not being returned by DoStuff yet, thus failing the whole operation.

Comment: @qualizon `DoStuff` doesn't touch your token.  `GetTokenAsync` is what provides the token.  It will have completed.  If it's returning `null`, then the definition of that method was to return `null`.  If it didn't finish, it wouldn't return `null`, rather `token` wouldn't be able to give you a value at all.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. The fact that token in null is probably because GetTokenAsync() returns null, and not because it hasn't completed. The await keyword places the lines following it into a continuation block, which gets executed when the task returned by GetTokenAsync() completes; and not any earlier.

Comment: @Servy, sorry, I mean GetTokenAsync when I say get the token. Have been a rough day today.

Comment: nothing wrong with it, debug the GetTokenAsync (it's probably there where the issue is) - and just get into the debugger, you'll see where it goes so it should help you clarify some things

Answer (score 0):

That code is right in the sense of it is waiting for the first `async` call, getting the result and then continuing with the second `async` call.